# why is my discord.py bot is not going online after deploying on heroku?

Tags: heroku, bots, discord.py

My bot.py 's code is :

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
from discord.ext.commands import bot
import asyncio
import requests
import os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")
.. Command's and stuff..
bot.run(str(os.environ.get('DISCORD_TOKEN')))
```

My requirements.txt consists of :

```
discord.py
requests
```

My Procfile consists of :

```
worker: python3 bot.py
```

I followed all steps to deploy through git and it successfully got deployed but still it's not online.

Comment: Provide the logs from heroku and also, did you start the dyno by scaling it?

Answer (score 0):

You bot doesn't go online because of your [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ). It doesn't have any `get` method since it's a [`Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-mapping) object. Here's how you use it:

```py
bot.run(os.environ['DISCORD_TOKEN'])
```

PS: you have some unecessary imports, like `from discord.ext.commands import bot`. You should only import what you need (eg. `from os import environ` instead of `import os`).

Comment: Also, his requirements.txt isn't comprehensive: it's missing the version numbers. Please do `pip freeze` and copy and paste the contents into that file, or you could also do `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.